# Finding the vertices of a regular n-sided polygon using its centroid

Tags: polar-coordinates, polygons

How do you find the vertices of a regular $n$-sided polygon using its centroid, with the knowledge that each vertice is distance $d$ from the centroid.

Comment: There is information missing. For instance, do you know the side length, or the apothem?